# AmCharts on iOS : Ranges aren't displayed correctly on export (Ionic App, AmCharts 4)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, png, amcharts

I'm looking for help as I really don't know where the bug would come from.

I have a chart in my Ionic App that is well displayed like that :
[chart well displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Foj86.jpg)

But when I export as png, the chart looks like that :
[badly displayed chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tu8CD.png)

The blue range totally changed here and I don't know why. Can you help me ?

The problem only appears on iOS

Comment: Did I'm missing something ? Why did my post get disliked ? Tell me if you need more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on amCharts JS library. If I comment a line in the case 1 of simplifiedImageExport function, this works well. Here is the line to delete :

```
case 1:
                    _a.trys.push([1, 6, , 7]);
                    canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
                    canvas.width = 1;
                    canvas.height = 1;
                    // Line to delete
                    // ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                    DOMURL = this.getDOMURL();
                    svg = new Blob([this.normalizeSVG("<g></g>", {}, 1, 1)], {
                        type: "image/svg+xml"
                    });
                    url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);
                    img = void 0;
                    _a.label = 2;
```